# Posix regular expression non capturing group

Tags: c, regex, linux, posix

I'm writing a simple shell in C under linux. I'm trying to parse user input with POSIX regex with group capturing. My problem is I dont want to capture all the groups, but the ?: symbol desnt seem to work for me.

```
"^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+)( [A-Za-z0-9]*(?:\"[^\"]*\")*(?:\'[^\']*\')*[A-Za-z0-9]*)*&?$"
```

Comment: It will match but it won't capture. Where is the code you are using?

Answer (score 12):

The use of `(?:..)`, or any other grouping prefix, is not allowed in [POSIX Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_05).

There are tools to make languages, [lex](/questions/tagged/lex) & [yacc](/questions/tagged/yacc) for example, and a simplified [yacc](/questions/tagged/yacc) grammar for POSIX shells [is provided by the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

Answer (score 3):

The character sequence `(?` is *undefined* as per section [9.4.3 ERE Special
Characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03):

> `*+?{`
>
> The `<asterisk>`, `<plus-sign>`, **`<question-mark>`**, and `<left-brace>` shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see RE Bracket Expression). Any of the following uses produce undefined results:
>
> - If these characters appear first in an ERE, or immediately following an unescaped `<vertical-line>`, `<circumflex>`, `<dollar-sign>`, or **`<left-parenthesis>`**
> - If a `<left-brace>` is not part of a valid interval expression (see EREs Matching Multiple Characters)

A POSIX RE implementation has a few choices for how to handle *undefined* syntax. Those choices include enabling an extended syntax as per section [9.1 Regular Expression Definitions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01_05). So it's free to implement the non-capturing group syntax:

> [...] violations of the specified syntax or semantics for REs produce
>   undefined results: this may entail an error, **enabling an extended
>   syntax for that RE**, or using the construct in error as literal
>   characters to be matched.

If you'd like to see the feature as part of a future POSIX standard, you could open an issue on the [standard's issue tracker](http://austingroupbugs.net).